# PUT-PIXEL in every language

Tags: code-golf, graphical-output

During work on some project I needed to draw pixels on screen. I found some put-pixel function in JS, but code was quite big and clumsy - so I wonder, how small put-pixel function can be...

## Challenge

Create the smallest put-pixel function.

We count size of whole program: **initialization code (if needed), function and code necessary to draw the test case witch 11 pixels**. If your language does not support functions, you can use what you have. Language must be capable of graphical output or drawing charts (saving files is not allowed).

The function (or program) should accept as input the following 6 independent integers pixel parameters (and other if needed):

- `x` from 0 to at least 255 - horizontal position
- `y` from 0 to at least 255 - vertical position
- `R` from 0 to 255 - red color component
- `G` from 0 to 255 - green color component
- `B` from 0 to 255 - blue color component
- `A` from 0 to 255 - alpha (if 0 then the pixel color is fully transparent, and we see old background pixel; if 255 then the pixel is completely opaque; for values 0<A<255 we calculate color in linear way, using the old and new pixel colors).

more parameters than above 6 is allowed and parameters can have any order. Number parameters can be strings and have base different than 10 or be coded in some way (if chosen language requires that).

## Test case

On output you should draw following test-case with 11 pixels (I will use `putPixel(x,y,R,G,B,A)` as example to show case)

```
putPixel(126, 127, 255,   0,   0, 255) // Red
putPixel(127, 127,   0, 255,   0, 255) // Green
putPixel(128, 127,   0,   0, 255, 255) // Blue
putPixel(129, 127, 255,   0,   0, 255) // Red
putPixel(129, 127,   0, 255,   0, 127) // Dark Yellow (previous red + transparent green)

putPixel(126, 128,   0,   0,   0, 255) // Black
putPixel(127, 128, 255, 255, 255, 255) // White
putPixel(128, 128, 255,   0,   0, 255) // Red
putPixel(128, 128,   0,   0, 255, 127) // Dark pink (previous red + transparent blue)
putPixel(129, 128,   0, 255,   0, 255) // Blue
putPixel(129, 128,   0,   0, 255, 127) // Dark sea-blue (previous blue + transparent green)
```

We should see 8 pixel (but we paint 11pixel, but 3 of them are transparent paints on already colored pixels).

[image]

**Leaderboard:**

```js
/* Configuration */

var QUESTION_ID = 250776; // Obtain this from the url
// It will be like https://XYZ.stackexchange.com/questions/QUESTION_ID/... on any question page
var ANSWER_FILTER = "!t)IWYnsLAZle2tQ3KqrVveCRJfxcRLe";
var COMMENT_FILTER = "!)Q2B_A2kjfAiU78X(md6BoYk";
var OVERRIDE_USER = 88163; // This should be the user ID of the challenge author.

/* App */

var answers = [], answers_hash, answer_ids, answer_page = 1, more_answers = true, comment_page;

function answersUrl(index) {
  return "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/" +  QUESTION_ID + "/answers?page=" + index + "&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter=" + ANSWER_FILTER;
}

function commentUrl(index, answers) {
  return "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/" + answers.join(';') + "/comments?page=" + index + "&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter=" + COMMENT_FILTER;
}

function getAnswers() {
  jQuery.ajax({
    url: answersUrl(answer_page++),
    method: "get",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    crossDomain: true,
    success: function (data) {
      answers.push.apply(answers, data.items);
      answers_hash = [];
      answer_ids = [];
      data.items.forEach(function(a) {
        a.comments = [];
        var id = +a.share_link.match(/\d+/);
        answer_ids.push(id);
        answers_hash[id] = a;
      });
      if (!data.has_more) more_answers = false;
      comment_page = 1;
      getComments();
    }
  });
}

function getComments() {
  jQuery.ajax({
    url: commentUrl(comment_page++, answer_ids),
    method: "get",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    crossDomain: true,
    success: function (data) {
      data.items.forEach(function(c) {
        if (c.owner.user_id === OVERRIDE_USER)
          answers_hash[c.post_id].comments.push(c);
      });
      if (data.has_more) getComments();
      else if (more_answers) getAnswers();
      else process();
    }
  });  
}

getAnswers();

var SCORE_REG = /<h\d>\s*([^\n,<]*(?:<(?:[^\n>]*>[^\n<]*<\/[^\n>]*>)[^\n,<]*)*),.*?(\d+)(?=[^\n\d<>]*(?:<(?:s>[^\n<>]*<\/s>|[^\n<>]+>)[^\n\d<>]*)*<\/h\d>)/;

var OVERRIDE_REG = /^Override\s*header:\s*/i;

function getAuthorName(a) {
  return a.owner.display_name;
}

function process() {
  var valid = [];
  
  answers.forEach(function(a) {
    var body = a.body;
    a.comments.forEach(function(c) {
      if(OVERRIDE_REG.test(c.body))
        body = '<h1>' + c.body.replace(OVERRIDE_REG, '') + '</h1>';
    });
    
    var match = body.match(SCORE_REG);
    if (match)
      valid.push({
        user: getAuthorName(a),
        size: +match[2],
        language: match[1],
        link: a.share_link,
      });
    else console.log(body);
  });
  
  valid.sort(function (a, b) {
    var aB = a.size,
        bB = b.size;
    return aB - bB
  });

  var languages = {};
  var place = 1;
  var lastSize = null;
  var lastPlace = 1;
  valid.forEach(function (a) {
    if (a.size != lastSize)
      lastPlace = place;
    lastSize = a.size;
    ++place;
    
    var answer = jQuery("#answer-template").html();
    answer = answer.replace("{{PLACE}}", lastPlace + ".")
                   .replace("{{NAME}}", a.user)
                   .replace("{{LANGUAGE}}", a.language)
                   .replace("{{SIZE}}", a.size)
                   .replace("{{LINK}}", a.link);
    answer = jQuery(answer);
    jQuery("#answers").append(answer);

    var lang = a.language;
    lang = jQuery('<a>'+lang+'</a>').text();
    
    languages[lang] = languages[lang] || {lang: a.language, lang_raw: lang, user: a.user, size: a.size, link: a.link};
  });

  var langs = [];
  for (var lang in languages)
    if (languages.hasOwnProperty(lang))
      langs.push(languages[lang]);

  langs.sort(function (a, b) {
    if (a.lang_raw.toLowerCase() > b.lang_raw.toLowerCase()) return 1;
    if (a.lang_raw.toLowerCase() < b.lang_raw.toLowerCase()) return -1;
    return 0;
  });

  for (var i = 0; i < langs.length; ++i)
  {
    var language = jQuery("#language-template").html();
    var lang = langs[i];
    language = language.replace("{{LANGUAGE}}", lang.lang)
                       .replace("{{NAME}}", lang.user)
                       .replace("{{SIZE}}", lang.size)
                       .replace("{{LINK}}", lang.link);
    language = jQuery(language);
    jQuery("#languages").append(language);
  }

}
```

```css
body {
  text-align: left !important;
  display: block !important;
}

#answer-list {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 290px;
  float: left;
}

#language-list {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 290px;
  float: left;
}

table thead {
  font-weight: bold;
}

table td {
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/codegolf/all.css?v=ffb5d0584c5f">
<div id="answer-list">
  <h2>Leaderboard</h2>
  <table class="answer-list">
    <thead>
      <tr><td></td><td>Author</td><td>Language</td><td>Size</td></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="answers">

    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<div id="language-list">
  <h2>Shortest Solution by Language</h2>
  <table class="language-list">
    <thead>
      <tr><td>Language</td><td>User</td><td>Score</td></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="languages">

    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<table style="display: none">
  <tbody id="answer-template">
    <tr><td>{{PLACE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<table style="display: none">
  <tbody id="language-template">
    <tr><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: If something is not clear in this question - write it in comments - I will edit it

Comment: Maybe you can clarify even better that test case input is also counted by highlighting ;-)

Comment: Request for clarification: other answerers have interpreted *"code necessary to draw the test case"* as including the test code itself, as opposed to just the code necessary to run it (as is more usual on Code Golf). If this is your intention, then how much are we allowed to golf the test code? If I declare `a=127`, `b=128`, `c=255` and so on it can save a few bytes, but also I can save bytes by replacing some of the calls to the `putPixel` function with others that achieve the same image output with fewer calls in total... and I'm sure you didn't intend to allow that. So where is the line?

Comment: @kaya3 **we count whole program (including test-case with 11 pixels)** - the idea behind this was to motivate authors to write function in such way that calling it is also cheap (not "eat" too many bytes). We use 11 pixels to test alpha-channel of course (this force authors to not only **put** pixels but also **read** old ones...)

Comment: From my understanding, the test case consists of eleven function calls, each taking six numbers as arguments that can each range from 0 to 255. In the special case provided, there are semitransparent pixels and transparent ones that create "new colors" in existing places. We could produce the exact same picture with eight function calls. As many values keep being the same throughout the testcase, we could also optimize the `putPixel` function itself with respect to the very test case, agreed. I also can't say how much we can/should optimize for the special test case.

Comment: Common sense, however, tells me that the first solution (C + sh + imagemagick) is "doing it right" in the sense that the function itself should be able to take arbitrary values. This is also consistent with the challenge: "The function (or program) should accept as input ..." Golfing the test case by introducing variables for common values, however, should not be prohibited in my opinion.

Comment: @Joe85AC If the function is required to take the six numbers (x,y,r,g,b,a) as arguments, then your TikZ solution, which takes 7 inputs - two for x, two for y, two for opacity and one for r,g,b - would not be allowed. (I also note that you save bytes by accepting the inputs in a different order - a before r,g,b.) But I would be inclined to allow your solution even though your function's signature is quite different. Counting the test code towards the program size seems like an unnecessary mess, IMO.

Comment: @kaya3 more than (x,y,r,g,b,a) is allowed (i try to write it in question by quote: "*(and other if needed)*" (more than 6 parameters is allowed) - I update question

Comment: @kaya3 Actually, I'm processing six two-digit hex integers. If the fact that the function is spliting them up internally makes it invalid, your solution is invalid as well, since you are treating arguments 4, 5, and 6 as an array, internally, and, thus, as a single argument. I believe, both of our solutions are valid, though.

Comment: @Joe85AC So for example, if I wrote `f(x,y,0x12345678)` in Javascript, would that count as two hexadecimal digits for each colour channel because those hex digits are literally present in the source code, or do the language's syntax and semantics (which specify that `0x12345678` is a single expression) matter?

Comment: @kaya3 In my opinion, it's OK to golf the input. And in your example provided, there are four hex numbers present that can each go up to 255. So everything would be fine with that I guess.

Comment: @Joe85AC OK, and then what if I replace `0xffffffff` (for opaque white) with the equivalent expression `-1>>>0`? The hex digits are no longer present in the source code, and the function doesn't take separate parameters for r,g,b,a, so it feels wrong, but also it feels wrong if I'm *not* allowed to do that. And how about if I write `'ffffffff'` as a string instead of an integer - the OP says they must be "integer parameters" but is it enough that a human reading the code can *interpret* them as integers? If not, what does this mean for your TikZ solution?

Comment: Then my TikZ-solution becomes wrong. :-/ ;-)

Comment: It seems I can get my solution down to 307 bytes if hex strings are allowed; perhaps @KamilKiełczewski can clarify?

Comment: @kaya3 I think that you question is theoretical, not trivial and goes far beyond this task. However I update my question

Comment: Indeed, it's not trivial, and I don't blame you for not wanting to specify your challenge in such detail. This is why Code Golf challenges normally don't count the size of the test code towards the score...

Comment: Regarding parameters, @kaya3: I believe it's OK to have as many/as few parameters as desired when defining the function as long as you can pass six (or more) values separately. It's OK if you pass a single array if it contains the three separate values for R, G and B. No need to restrict input that much. Where's the (more than technical) difference if you write p(x,y,[R,G,B],A) instead of p(x,y,R,G,B,A) or p(xxyyRRGGBBaa)? You should, however, imho not mix multiple values into one parameter, e.g. 16777215 for FFFFFF meaning "white" since you cannot change the inputs independently in this case.

Answer (score 6):

## TikZ, <s>333, 322,</s> 307 bytes

- Wrapper (`\documentclass...`, `\begin...`/`\end{document}`, and `\tikz{}`): 66 bytes
- Definition of Macro `~`: <s>113, 112</s> 97 bytes
- Test Cases: 14 + 10 x 13 bytes = 144 bytes (<s>154 bytes</s>)

### Compact Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}\def~{document}\begin~\tikz{\def~#1#2#3#4#5#6#7;{\color[HTML]{#7}\fill[opacity=(0x#5#6)/255](0x#1#2,-0x#3#4)rectangle++(,);~}~7E7FFFff0000;7F7FFF00ff00;807FFF0000ff;817FFFff0000;817F7F00ff00;7E80FF000000;7F80FFffffff;8080FFff0000;80807F0000ff;8180FF00ff00;81807F0000ff;}\end~
```

[Try It Online](https://www.overleaf.com/read/xwtkwtwbxyxk)

### Output

[image: PNG version of the PDF output]

The code produces a PDF file (vector graphic image); the picture above is a PNG image produced by conversion via pdf2png.com.

### Readable Version of the Code

```
01: \documentclass[tikz]{standalone}\def~{document}\begin~\tikz{
02: \def~#1#2#3#4#5#6#7;{
03:     \color[HTML]{#7}
04:     \fill[opacity=(0x#5#6)/255]
05:     (0x#1#2,-0x#3#4)rectangle++(,);
06: ~}
07: ~7E7FFFff0000;
08: 7F7FFF00ff00;
09: 807FFF0000ff;
10: 817FFFff0000;
11: 817F7F00ff00;
12: 7E80FF000000;
13: 7F80FFffffff;
14: 8080FFff0000;
15: 80807F0000ff;
16: 8180FF00ff00;
17: 81807F0000ff;
18: }\end~
```

### Explanation

**Lines 1 and 18**

Defining `~` as `document` outside of the document-scope allows for saving three bytes when writing `\begin~` and `\end~`. Note: `~` is the only "active char" in LaTeX.

**Lines 2 and 6**

Defining `~` within the document-scope does not interfere with the definition outside of the document scope. We define `~` to be a macro with seven parameters,

- parameters 1 and 2 being the two hex digits for the x-coordinate,
- parameters 3 and 4 being the two hex digits for the y-coordinate,
- parameters 5 and 6 being the two hex digits for the opacity, and
- parameter 7 being the color which will be provided as HTML color.

`;` denotes the end of the HTML color string. We could omit this if we used a [technique that helps to use more than nine arguments.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2132/how-to-define-a-command-that-takes-more-than-9-arguments) However, we don't use this approach here because using more than nine arguments would add more than the 11 bytes (coming from the eleven `;` in the eleven test cases) that we could possibly save. Note that if we had to deal with several hundred test cases, we would rather opt for omitting the `;` and, thus, for allowing for more than nine arguments.

The definition of the macro ends with `}` in line 7. Before ending the definition, we call the macro itself again. This allows us to refrain from repeating the `~` character multiple times when inputting the test case. Note that this produces a "recoverable error" when the last pixel is printed. However, a graphical output is generated nevertheless.

**Line 3**

We define the color that we will use to draw the pixel. The RGB values provided in the test cases have been converted to the HTML model in the obvious manner. Since we are required to use integers, we note explicitly that we do observe this requirement by making use of *hex integers!*

**Line 4**

We use the `\fill`-command to draw the pixel, and we set the opacity.

**Line 5**

We provide the coordinates as hex integers. Note that the y-coordinate is prefixed with a `-` because TikZ has its origin in the bottom left corner of the screen whereas the task provides a test case output that clearly shows its origin to be in the top left corner of the screen. The height and the width of each pixel will be 1 cm. `(,)` is equivalent to `(1,1)`. The standard unit for coordinates is centimeter.

We also close the scope of the definition of `~` as shorthand for `numexpr`.

**Lines 7, 8, ..., 17**

Test cases / output.

### Improvements

Please help me to get better. If you know TikZ and if you can save some more bytes, please make sure to comment on this solution. Thank you!

Comment:  (you win "currently shortest answer" mark (which can be temporary))

Answer (score 4):

## C (tcc) + sh + imagemagick, 454 bytes

- C code: 434 bytes (removing newlines)
- filename: 1 byte
- shell command: 18 bytes

--

```
#define p(x,y,R,G,B,A){int*j=i+(x+y*w)*3,C[3]={R,G,B};for(k=0;k<3;++k)j[k]=(C[k]*A+j[k]*(w-A))/w;}
w=255;c;
main(k){
int*i=calloc(w*w,12);
p(126,127,255,0,0,255)
p(127,127,0,255,0,255)
p(128,127,0,0,255,255)
p(129,127,255,0,0,255)
p(129,127,0,255,0,127)
p(126,128,0,0,0,255)
p(127,128,255,255,255,255)
p(128,128,255,0,0,255)
p(128,128,0,0,255,127)
p(129,128,0,255,0,255)
p(129,128,0,0,255,127)
puts("P6 255 255 255");
for(;c<w*w*3;)
putchar(i[c++]);
}
```

Assuming the code is saved in a file named `a`, run `tcc -run a|display`.

Comment: 1️⃣ <- this is "first answer silver medal" for you :)

Comment: When creating my solution, the requirement "at least 255" immediately pointed me to 2-digit hex integers. You might want to check whether this thought might save you a couple of bytes... ;-)

Answer (score 4):

## C#, .NET 6.0, Windows Forms, <strike>452</strike> <strike>443</strike> 435 bytes

`Application.EnableVisualStyles();Form F=new();List<int[]>L=new();void P(params int[]a)=>L.Add(a);F.Paint+=(s,e)=>L.ForEach(p=>e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(p[5],p[2],p[3],p[4])),p[0],p[1],1,1));int a=127,b=128,c=129,z=255;P(126,a,z,0,0,z);P(a,a,0,z,0,z);P(b,a,0,0,z,z);P(c,a,z,0,0,z);P(c,a,0,z,0,a);P(126,b,0,0,0,z);P(a,b,z,z,z,z);P(b,b,z,0,0,z);P(b,b,0,0,z,a);P(c,b,0,z,0,z);P(c,b,0,0,z,a);Application.Run(F);`

To run this, put the above in a file, e.g. `x.cs` and create a project file, e.g. `x.csproj` as follows:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
        <TargetFramework>net6.0-windows</TargetFramework>
        <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
        <UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>
    </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Then run it with `dotnet run`.

Explanation:

```
// Initialise graphics
Application.EnableVisualStyles();
var F=new Form();

// Definition of the function P adds its parameters to a list of pixels
var L=new List<int[]>();
void P(params int[]a)=>L.Add(a);

// Paint method fills a rectangle for each pixel in the list
F.Paint+=(s,e)=>L.ForEach(p=>e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(p[5],p[2],p[3],p[4])),p[0],p[1],1,1));

// Test case (golfed)
int a=127,b=128,c=129,z=255;
P(126,a,z,0,0,z);
P(a,a,0,z,0,z);
P(b,a,0,0,z,z);
P(c,a,z,0,0,z);
P(c,a,0,z,0,a);
P(126,b,0,0,0,z);
P(a,b,z,z,z,z);
P(b,b,z,0,0,z);
P(b,b,0,0,z,a);
P(c,b,0,z,0,z);
P(c,b,0,0,z,a);

// Finally run the application
Application.Run(F);
```

#### Improvements

- Use `new()` syntax to save the bytes of `var`
- Use the `Graphics` property of the `PaintEventArgs` instead of calling `CreateGraphics()` on the `Form`.

Comment: [359 bytes](https://tio.run/##TU9BasMwEPyKjxLeitht0hZVhbTgXnoo6TH4IMmyLVAkIzstKOTtrmUHU5bdmV1mBlb2d9J5NY4/3Cc1s@o3KZw/IUxr8sW1HVKGelCYvV6mJeEsyx9BTPMJ5DSfIbB8uwXNNjQmVDHhWF6yfAccAmymChPjM8YWM48sgPynkauGQ3SL@b64xawOs1usDnHTRIWcebglrfcrrZ1HVL9U5FPZZmipTtkOK/Lheddq2ZNCG3NQcuC2MQrF97@d0dWbP/ctenfGeVJ4d9r7RqDqqNNtCRHyBe4XeCgxjmTZshIyyDC90n3XGS35oJ0lh7NFNabj@Ac)

Comment: Sure, jdt, your code is shorter but it doesn't include a Put-Pixel function that you can call to draw a pixel. You just have pixel data in an array, not a function.

Comment: point taken ;-) You don't really need `Application.EnableVisualStyles();` and the following saves a couple of bytes: `F.Paint+=(s,e)=>L.ForEach(p=>e.Graphics.DrawArc(new Pen(Color.FromArgb(p[5],p[2],p[3],p[4])),p[0],p[1],1,1,0,9));`.

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript + Canvas, <s>405</s> 329 bytes

```js
d=document
d.body.append(c=d.createElement('canvas'))
c=c.getContext('2d')
p=(x,y,a,...r)=>{c.fillStyle=`rgba(${r},${a/k})`;c.fillRect(x,y,1,1)}
p(126,g=127,k=255,k,0,0)
p(g,g,k,0,k,0)
p(h=128,g,k,0,0,k)
p(j=129,g,k,k,0,0)
p(j,g,g,0,k,0)
p(126,h,k,0,0,0)
p(g,h,k,k,k,k)
p(h,h,k,k,0,0)
p(h,h,g,0,0,k)
p(j,h,k,0,k,0)
p(j,h,g,0,0,k)
```

The fill-style is set by coercing an array to a string in order to get the commas, and also to save on declaring a couple of parameters.

The alpha parameter is taken before the r,g,b rest parameter, and it has to be divided by 255; it saves two bytes to reuse the variable `k` for this, which is assigned on the next line but that occurs before the function is called for the first time. This raises the question of whether the function itself is allowed to depend on the test code...

Thanks to @Kaiido for informing me about `append` (vs. `appendChild`).

Without the test code, it would be 146 bytes (including +2 for replacing `k` with `255`).

Comment: Sorry to bother, but you will have to count the input for the text cases as well. That's stated in the rules. Even if we omit "wrappers" like `<script></script>` that you will most certainly need for your code to be executed, this solution is at least 244 bytes LONGER. Those bytes come from the way you formulate your test cases... :-/

Comment: @Joe85AC The OP says to count *"initialization code (if needed), function and code necessary to draw the test case"*, I would normally interpret "code necessary to draw the test case" as not including the code that actually performs the test, particularly because that is normal on Code Golf and also generally a test is not part of the program it is testing. But I see your answer and the other one have included the test code in the byte count too. I will edit, but I think the OP should clarify this, because it also raises the question of how much we're allowed to golf the test code...

Comment: By the way, you don't need to write any HTML tags to execute JavaScript code - you can paste it straight into the browser console, for example.

Comment: Agreed: HTML tags are not needed. You're completely right here. On a side note: Golfing your input with parseInt(...,16) might save a few bytes.

Comment: Yes, the input can definitely be golfed further but it is not clear to me how much I'm allowed to golf it before it counts as "not the same test case" any more. Normally Code Golf challenges are judged as correct if they have the correct output, but here I am sure it would not be allowed to replace two `putPixel` calls at the same coordinates with one, for example; so I will wait for the OP to specify the rules more clearly before I try to save any more bytes.

Comment: You can reduce a lot of the test-case payload by saving `127`,`128`,`129`, and `255` in variables. You can also shave a few bytes in the init part by using the return value of `appendChild()`:  `c=(d=document).body.appendChild(d.createElement('canvas')).getContext('2d'),`; And that gives us a [337 version](https://jsfiddle.net/pnds6x0g/).

Comment: @Kaiido I did not know about `appendChild` returning the element - that is useful, thank you. I'm aware that the test code can be golfed, but that is an unusual allowance on this site, so I will wait for OP to clarify what the rules for golfing the test code are.

Comment: Well I'm not really very familiar with the rules here either but lurking around I'd say it's quite unusual to have the test case count in the score at all. So if it does, it only makes sense that it ought to be golfable too. I mean you're just unlucky that the question used a syntax that does look like JS. Other languages wouldn't have this issue.

Comment: Oh and actually using `.append()` saves one byte over `appendChild()`: https://jsfiddle.net/pnds6x0g/1/

Comment: Right, but *how* golfable should it be? It would certainly be against the spirit of the challenge to replace transparent pixels with opaque ones that produce the same output, for example, and it also seems wrong to change the function body so that I can pass `y` as 0 or 1 instead of 127 or 128. But removing whitespace is clearly OK. So there is a line to be drawn somewhere, and I will wait until it's drawn.

Comment: @kaya3 **we count whole program (including test-case with 11 pixels)** - the idea behind this was to motivate authors to write function in such way that calling it is also cheap (not "eat" too many bytes). We use 11 pixels to test alpha-channel of course (this force authors to not only **put** pixels but also **read** old ones...)

Comment: @Kaiido Thanks for the `appendChild`!

Comment: this version of answer not meet requirements (6 independent parameters are mandatory)

Comment: @KamilKiełczewski But in Joe85AC's TikZ answer, the r,g,b values are also passed together as a single parameter; and in a previous version of my answer, they were passed as a single parameter (an array). I will revert, but this seems pretty arbitrary to me...

Comment: @kaya3 - nope - his function definition,  contains 6 mandatory parameters (and bonus one): `\def~#1#2#3#4#5#6#7;{...` - but your definition contains only 3 parameters: `p=(x,y,r)=>{...`. (in [this version](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/revisions/250808/6) of your answer we're talking about)

Comment: @KamilKiełczewski But his first two parameters are *both* for x, the next two are *both* for y, the next two are *both* for alpha, and his remaining one parameter is for red green and blue together. If it's simply about the number of parameters the function has, then I can add some unused parameters, but surely that wouldn't make you satisfied.

Comment: @kaya3 if so then he must change definition of his parameters

Comment: Save 4 bytes by calling functions as a [tagged template](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#tagged_templates)

Answer (score 2):

## Java 8, <s>441</s> 433 bytes

```java
import java.awt.*;class M{static Graphics g;public static void main(String[]s){new Frame(){public void paint(Graphics G){g=G;int a=127,b=128,z=255;p(126,a,z,0,0,z);p(a,a,0,z,0,z);p(b,a,0,0,z,z);p(129,a,z,0,0,z);p(129,a,0,z,0,a);p(126,b,0,0,0,z);p(a,b,z,z,z,z);p(b,b,z,0,0,z);p(b,b,0,0,z,a);p(129,b,0,z,0,z);p(129,b,0,0,z,a);}{show();}};}static void p(int...a){g.setColor(new Color(a[2],a[3],a[4],a[5]));g.fillRect(a[0],a[1],10,10);}}
```

Java is one of the reasons why we allow both programs and functions for codegolf challenges, since the additional fluff is so dang verbose.. :/

- Initialization code: 146 bytes
- Actual draw pixel method: 88 bytes
- 11 test cases: 199 bytes

**Explanation:**

*Initialization code:*

```java
import java.awt.*;        // Required import for Frame, Graphics, and Color
class M{                  // Class
  static Graphics g;      //  With (static) class-variable Graphics object to save bytes
  public static void main(String[]s){
                          //  Mandatory main method
    new Frame(){          //   Create a new Frame to draw on
      public void paint(Graphics G){
                          //    Overwrite its paint method
        g=G;              //     Set the class-variable Graphics object
                          /*     Test cases */
      }                   //    Close the paint-method
      {                   //    Open an initializer-block of the Frame:
        show();           //     Show the Frame
      }                   //    Close the initializer-block
    };                    //   Close the Frame
  }                       //  Close the main-method
  static                  //  Static block for the draw pixel method
                          /*  Draw pixel method */
}                         // Close the class
```

*Draw pixel method:*

```java
void p(int...a){          // Draw pixel method with variable length integer parameters
  g.setColor(new Color(   //  Set a new color
    a[2],a[3],a[4],a[5]));//  using the 3rd to 6th parameters as red,green,blue,alpha
  g.fillRect(             //  And create a rectangle
    a[0],a[1],            //  at x,y-position using the 1st & 2nd parameters
    1,1);                 //  of 1 by 1 pixel
}                         // Close the draw pixel method
```

*Test cases:*

```java
int a=127,b=128,z=255;    // Create three variables to save bytes
p(126,a,z,0,0,z);p(a,a,0,z,0,z);p(b,a,0,0,z,z);p(129,a,z,0,0,z);p(129,a,0,z,0,a);p(126,b,0,0,0,z);p(a,b,z,z,z,z);p(b,b,z,0,0,z);p(b,b,0,0,z,a);p(129,b,0,z,0,z);p(129,b,0,0,z,a);
                          // Draw the 11 pixels
```

**Screenshot (using enlarged 10x10 pixels instead of 1x1):**

[image]

Comment: This Golf seems to be made for Java if we only look at the actual function. 88 bytes is brilliant!

Comment: @Joe85AC Java always has tons of boilerplate, making seemingly good answers into bad ones

Answer (score 2):

## C + Win32 GDI, 508 bytes

```c
#include<Windows.h>
A=127,B=128,C=129,Z=255;h,d,o,c,m;p(x,y,R,G,B,a){o=GetPixel(d=GetDC(h),x,y),c=RGB(R,G,B);SetPixel(d,x,y,((((256-a)*(o&0xFF00FF))>>8|(a*(c&0xFF00FF))>>8)&0xFF00FF)+((((256-a)*(o&65280))>>8|(a*(c&65280))>>8)&65280));}main(){for(h=CreateWindow("STATIC","",1<<28,0,0,Z,Z,0,0,0,0);GetMessage(&m,h,0,0);)DispatchMessage(&m),p(126,A,Z,0,0,Z),p(A,A,0,Z,0,Z),p(B,A,0,0,Z,Z),p(C,A,Z,0,0,Z),p(C,A,0,Z,0,A),p(126,B,0,0,0,Z),p(A,B,Z,Z,Z,Z),p(B,B,Z,0,0,Z),p(B,B,0,0,Z,A),p(C,B,0,Z,0,Z),p(C,B,0,0,Z,A);}
```

Slightly ungolfed:

```c
#include <Windows.h>

int h, d, o, c, m;

p(x, y, R, G, B, a)
{
    d = GetDC(h);
    o = GetPixel(d, x, y);
    c = RGB(R, G, B);
    SetPixel(d, x, y, ((((0x100 - a) * (o & 0xFF00FF)) >> 8 | (a * (c & 0xFF00FF)) >> 8) & 0xFF00FF) + ((((0x100 - a) * (o & 65280)) >> 8 | (a * (c & 65280)) >> 8) & 65280));
}

main()
{
    h = CreateWindow("STATIC", "", 1 << 28, 0, 0, 199, 199, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    while (GetMessage(&m, h, 0, 0))
    {
        DispatchMessage(&m);
        int A = 127, B = 128, C = 129, Z = 255;
        p(126, A, Z, 0, 0, Z);
        p(A, A, 0, Z, 0, Z);
        p(B, A, 0, 0, Z, Z);
        p(C, A, Z, 0, 0, Z);
        p(C, A, 0, Z, 0, A);
        p(126, B, 0, 0, 0, Z);
        p(A, B, Z, Z, Z, Z);
        p(B, B, Z, 0, 0, Z);
        p(B, B, 0, 0, Z, A);
        p(C, B, 0, Z, 0, Z);
        p(C, B, 0, 0, Z, A);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [JSFuck](https://github.com/aemkei/jsfuck), <s>30220 29681 29542</s> 29353 bytes

This is JSFuck (subset of JS which use only `[]()!+` characters) port of [this solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/250829/88163)

```js
[][[]+([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]][[]+([]+[][[]+([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[][[]+([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]])[[]+(+!![])+(+[])]+([]+[][[]])[+!![]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]+([]+!![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+[][[]+([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]+(!![]+[][[]+([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]])[[]+(+!![])+(+[])]+([]+!![])[+!![]]](([]+(+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+[])+(+!![])+![]+!![]+!![]+(+!![])+![]+(+[])+!![]+(+!![])+!![]+(+!![])+(+!![])+(+!![])+![]+!![]+(+!![])+(+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+!![])+(+!![])+![]+!![]+![]+(+!![])+!![]+(+!![])+(+[])+(+[])+![]+!![]+![]+(+!![])+!![]+(+!![])+!![]+(+!![])+!![]+(+[])+![]+(+!![])+![]+![]+(+!![])+(+!![])+!![]+(+!![])+(+[])+(+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+!![])+(+!![])+![]+(+[])+(+[])+(+[])+!![]+!![]+(+[])+(+!![])+![]+(+[])+!![]+(+!![])+![]+(+[])+(+!![])+(+!![])+![]+!![]+![]+(+!![])+!![]+(+!![])+![]+(+!![])+![]+(+[])+(+!![])+(+!![])+!![]+(+[])+!![]+(+[])+![]+(+[])+(+[])+(+!![])+![]+![]+(+!![])+(+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+[])+(+[])+!![]+!![]+(+!![])+(+!![])+(+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+[])+!![]+!![]+![]+(+!![])+![]+(+[])+(+[])+(+[])+(+[])+![]+![]+(+!![])+![]+(+[])+!![]+(+[])+!![]+!![]+(+!![])+(+!![])+(+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+[])+![]+!![]+![]+(+!![])+![]+(+!![])+!![]+(+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+!![])+(+!![])+!![]+(+!![])+(+[])+(+!![])+(+[])+(+[])+!![]+(+!![])+![]+!![]+!![]+(+!![])+![]+!![]+![]+(+!![])+!![]+(+!![])+(+[])+(+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+!![])+(+!![])+!![]+![]+(+[])+(+!![])+!![]+(+!![])+(+[])+(+!![])+![]+(+[])+(+[])+(+[])+!![]+(+[])+![]+(+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+[])+(+!![])+![]+(+[])+(+[])+(+[])+(+[])+![]+![]+(+!![])+!![]+(+[])+(+[])+(+[])+!![]+!![]+(+!![])+(+[])+![]+![]+(+[])+(+!![])+!![]+![]+(+[])+(+[])+![]+!![]+(+[])+(+!![])+!![]+![]+(+!![])+(+[])+![]+!![]+(+[])+(+!![])+![]+(+[])+(+!![])+(+[])+![]+!![]+(+[])+(+[])+![]+!![]+![]+(+[])+![]+!![]+![]+(+[])+![]+!![]+![]+(+!![])+!![]+(+[])+![]+(+[])+![]+![]+(+!![])+(+[])+!![]+!![]+(+!![])+(+[])+!![]+!![]+![]+(+!![])+!![]+![]+!![]+(+!![])+![]+(+[])+!![]+(+[])+![]+!![]+![]+(+!![])+![]+(+!![])+![]+(+!![])+![]+![]+(+!![])+(+!![])+![]+!![]+(+[])+(+!![])+![]+!![]+(+[])+(+!![])+(+!![])+(+[])+!![]+(+!![])+!![]+(+!![])+(+[])+(+!![])+!![]+![]+(+!![])+(+!![])+![]+!![]+(+[])+(+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+!![])+(+[])+!![]+!![]+(+!![])+(+!![])+![]+(+[])+(+[])+(+!![])+!![]+(+[])+![]+(+!![])+![]+(+!![])+!![]+(+!![])+![]+(+[])+![]+(+!![])+![]+(+[])+(+!![])+(+[])+![]+![]+(+[])+(+[])+![]+(+!![])+(+[])+(+!![])+!![]+![]+!![]+(+!![])+!![]+(+[])+![]+(+!![])+!![]+!![]+(+!![])+(+[])+![]+!![]+(+[])+(+[])+![]+(+!![])+(+[])+(+!![])+!![]+![]+!![]+(+!![])+![]+(+[])+(+!![])+(+[])+![]+!![]+!![]+(+[])+!![]+(+[])+![]+(+[])+!![]+(+!![])+(+!![])+(+[])+!![]+(+!![])+(+!![])+(+!![])+!![]+!![]+(+!![])+(+[])+![]+![]+(+!![])+(+!![])+![]+(+[])+(+[])+(+[])+!![]+![]+!![]+(+!![])+![]+(+[])+!![]+(+[])+![]+!![]+![]+(+!![])+![]+(+!![])+![]+(+!![])+![]+![]+(+!![])+(+!![])+![]+!![]+(+[])+(+!![])+![]+!![]+(+[])+(+!![])+(+!![])+(+[])+![]+(+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+!![])+(+!![])+![]+(+[])+!![]+(+!![])+!![]+(+!![])+(+[])+(+[])+![]+![]+(+[])+(+!![])+!![]+![]+(+[])+(+[])+![]+!![]+(+[])+(+!![])+!![]+![]+(+!![])+(+[])+![]+!![]+(+[])+(+[])+!![]+(+[])+(+!![])+(+[])+![]+!![]+(+[])+(+[])+!![]+(+[])+(+!![])+(+[])+![]+![]+(+!![])+(+!![])+!![]+!![]+(+!![])+(+[])+(+[])+![]+![]+(+[])+![]+![]+(+[])+(+[])+!![]+(+[])+(+[])+(+!![])+!![]+![]+(+[])+(+[])+!![]+(+[])+(+!![])+(+[])+!![]+(+[])+!![]+(+[])+!![]+(+[])+(+!![])+(+[])+!![]+(+[])+(+!![])+(+[])+!![]+(+[])+![]+(+!![])+![]+(+!![])+![]+(+!![])+![]+(+[])+![]+(+[])+!![]+(+!![])+(+!![])+(+[])+!![]+(+!![])+![]+(+[])+!![]+(+!![])+(+!![])+(+[])+!![]+![]+(+!![])+(+[])+!![]+(+[])+![]+(+[])+!![]+(+[])+(+!![])+(+[])+!![]+(+[])+!![]+(+[])+!![]+![]+(+!![])+(+[])+!![]+(+[])+(+[])+(+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+!![])+(+[])+!![]+(+[])+(+!![])+(+[])+!![]+(+!![])+(+!![])+(+[])+!![]+(+[])+![]+(+[])+!![]+(+!![])+(+!![])+(+!![])+![]+(+[])+(+!![])+(+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+[])+(+[])+!![]+(+!![])+(+!![])+(+[])+!![]+(+[])+![]+(+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+!![])+(+[])+!![]+(+[])+![]+(+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+[])+(+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+!![])+(+!![])+![]+(+[])+![]+(+!![])+![]+(+[])+![]+(+[])+!![]+(+[])+![]+(+[])+!![]+(+[])+!![]+(+[])+!![]+(+!![])+(+!![])+(+!![])+![]+(+!![])+![]+(+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+[])+(+!![])+![]+(+[])+![]+(+[])+!![]+(+!![])+(+[])+(+[])+!![]+![]+(+[])+(+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+[])+(+!![])+![]+(+[])+!![]+(+[])+!![]+(+!![])+(+[])+(+[])+!![]+![]+(+!![])+(+[])+!![]+(+!![])+(+!![])+(+!![])+![]+(+[])+![]+(+[])+!![]+(+!![])+!![]+(+!![])+![]+(+[])+![]+(+[])+!![]+(+!![])+![]+(+[])+!![]+![]+(+!![])+(+[])+!![]+(+!![])+(+!![])+(+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+!![])+(+[])+!![]+(+[])+(+!![])+(+[])+!![]+(+!![])+![]+(+[])+!![]+(+[])+(+[])+(+[])+!![]+(+!![])+(+!![])+(+!![])+![]+!![]+![]+(+[])+![]+![]+!![]+(+[])+![]+(+!![])+!![]+(+[])+![]+(+!![])+!![]+(+[])+![]+![]+(+!![])+(+[])+![]+!![]+![]+(+!![])+!![]+(+[])+![]+(+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+!![])+(+!![])+!![]+(+[])+(+[])+(+!![])+![]+!![]+(+[])+(+!![])+![]+(+[])+(+!![])+(+!![])+![]+(+[])+!![]+(+!![])+![]+(+!![])+(+!![])+(+[])+![]+![]+(+[])+(+[])+![]+!![]+!![]+(+[])+![]+!![]+![]+(+!![])+!![]+![]+!![]+(+[])+!![]+(+!![])+![]+(+!![])+!![]+!![]+(+!![])+(+[])+![]+!![]+!![]+(+!![])+![]+(+!![])+!![]+(+[])+![]+!![]+(+[])+(+!![])+!![]+![]+(+[])+(+[])+!![]+!![]+(+!![])+(+[])+!![]+!![]+![]+(+!![])+!![]+(+[])+(+[])+(+[])+![]+![]+(+[])+(+[])+![]+!![]+![]+(+[])+![]+!![]+![]+(+[])+![]+!![]+![]+(+!![])+(+!![])+![]+!![]+(+[])+![]+!![]+![]+(+[])+![]+!![]+![]+(+[])+![]+!![]+![]+(+!![])+!![]+![]+(+[])+(+!![])+(+!![])+!![]+(+!![])+(+[])+![]+!![]+![]+(+!![])+![]+!![]+(+!![])+(+!![])+![]+(+[])+(+!![])+(+!![])+!![]+(+[])+(+[])+(+[])+![]+![]+(+[])+(+!![])+!![]+(+!![])+(+!![])+(+[])+!![]+!![]+(+!![])+(+[])+!![]+!![]+![]+(+!![])+(+!![])+![]+!![]+(+[])+!![]+(+[])+(+[])+(+[])+![]+!![]+(+[])+(+[])+!![]+(+[])+(+!![])+(+[])+!![]+(+[])+![]+(+[])+!![]+(+!![])+![]+(+[])+![]+!![]+(+[])+(+[])+!![]+(+[])+(+!![])+(+[])+!![]+(+[])+![]+(+[])+!![]+(+!![])+!![]+(+[])+![]+!![]+(+[])+(+[])+!![]+(+[])+(+!![])+(+[])+!![]+(+[])+![]+(+[])+!![]+![]+(+[])+(+[])+![]+!![]+(+[])+(+[])+!![]+(+[])+(+!![])+(+[])+!![]+(+[])+![]+(+[])+!![]+![]+(+!![])+(+[])+![]+!![]+(+[])+(+[])+!![]+(+[])+![]+(+[])+!![]+(+!![])+(+!![])+(+[])+!![]+(+!![])+(+!![])+(+!![])+(+!![])+!![]+(+!![])+(+!![])+(+!![])+![]+!![]+(+!![])+!![]+(+!![])+(+!![])+(+!![])+(+!![])+!![]+(+!![])+(+[])+![]+![]+(+!![])+(+[])+![]+![]+(+!![])+(+[])+![]+![]+(+!![]))[[]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(+([]+(!![]+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])))[[]+([]+!![])[+![]]+(!![]+[][[]+([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]])[[]+(+!![])+(+[])]+([]+[])[[]+([]+[][[]+([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[][[]+([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]])[[]+(+!![])+(+[])]+([]+[][[]])[+!![]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]+([]+!![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+[][[]+([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]+(!![]+[][[]+([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]])[[]+(+!![])+(+[])]+([]+!![])[+!![]]][[]+([]+[][[]])[+!![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+((+[])[[]+([]+[][[]+([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[][[]+([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]])[[]+(+!![])+(+[])]+([]+[][[]])[+!![]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]+([]+!![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+[][[]+([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]+(!![]+[][[]+([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]])[[]+(+!![])+(+[])]+([]+!![])[+!![]]]+[])[[]+(+!![])+(+!![])]+([]+!![])[!![]+!![]+!![]]]](+([]+(!![]+!![]+!![])+(+[])))+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+[][[]])[!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]]([]+!![])[[]+([][[]+([]+!![])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+([]+[][[]])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]+([]+!![])[+!![]]+([]+[][[]])[!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]]+([]+!![])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]+!![]]]()+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[][[]+([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]])[[]+(+!![])+(+[])]+([]+[][[]])[!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]]+([]+[][[]])[+!![]]](!![]+!![]+!![])[[]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(+([]+(!![]+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])))[[]+([]+!![])[+![]]+(!![]+[][[]+([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]])[[]+(+!![])+(+[])]+([]+[])[[]+([]+[][[]+([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[][[]+([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]])[[]+(+!![])+(+[])]+([]+[][[]])[+!![]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]+([]+!![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+[][[]+([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]+(!![]+[][[]+([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]])[[]+(+!![])+(+[])]+([]+!![])[+!![]]][[]+([]+[][[]])[+!![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+((+[])[[]+([]+[][[]+([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[][[]+([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]])[[]+(+!![])+(+[])]+([]+[][[]])[+!![]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]+([]+!![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+[][[]+([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]+(!![]+[][[]+([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]])[[]+(+!![])+(+[])]+([]+!![])[+!![]]]+[])[[]+(+!![])+(+!![])]+([]+!![])[!![]+!![]+!![]]]](+([]+(!![]+!![]+!![])+(+[])))+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+[][[]])[!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]]([]+![])[[]+([][[]+([]+!![])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+([]+[][[]])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]+([]+!![])[+!![]]+([]+[][[]])[!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]]+([]+!![])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]+!![]]]()+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[][[]+([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]])[[]+(+!![])+(+[])]+([]+[][[]])[!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]]+([]+[][[]])[+!![]]](!![]+!![])[[]+((+[])[[]+([]+[][[]+([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[][[]+([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]])[[]+(+!![])+(+[])]+([]+[][[]])[+!![]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]+([]+!![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+[][[]+([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]+(!![]+[][[]+([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]])[[]+(+!![])+(+[])]+([]+!![])[+!![]]]+[])[[]+(+!![])+(+!![])]+([]+![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]+([]+[][[]+([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(+([]+(+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])))[[]+([]+!![])[+![]]+(!![]+[][[]+([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]])[[]+(+!![])+(+[])]+([]+[])[[]+([]+[][[]+([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[][[]+([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]])[[]+(+!![])+(+[])]+([]+[][[]])[+!![]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]+([]+!![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+[][[]+([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]+(!![]+[][[]+([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]])[[]+(+!![])+(+[])]+([]+!![])[+!![]]][[]+([]+[][[]])[+!![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+((+[])[[]+([]+[][[]+([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[][[]+([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]])[[]+(+!![])+(+[])]+([]+[][[]])[+!![]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]+([]+!![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+[][[]+([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]+(!![]+[][[]+([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]])[[]+(+!![])+(+[])]+([]+!![])[+!![]]]+[])[[]+(+!![])+(+!![])]+([]+!![])[!![]+!![]+!![]]]](+([]+(!![]+!![])+(+[])))]([][[]+([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]][[]+([]+[][[]+([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[][[]+([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]])[[]+(+!![])+(+[])]+([]+[][[]])[+!![]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]+([]+!![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+[][[]+([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]+(!![]+[][[]+([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]])[[]+(+!![])+(+[])]+([]+!![])[+!![]]]([]+([]+!![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]+([]+!![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+!![])[+!![]]+([]+[][[]])[+!![]]+(![]+[+[]])[[]+([]+[][[]])[!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+[][[]])[!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]]+([]+[][[]+([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]+!![]]]()[[]+(+!![])+(+[])]+(+(+!+[]+[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]]+[+[]])+[])[+!+[]]+(+(+!+[]+[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]]+[+[]])+[])[+!+[]]+(+(+!+[]+[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]]+[+[]])+[])[+!+[]]+(+(+!+[]+[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]]+[+[]])+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[+[]])[[]+([]+[][[]])[!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+[][[]])[!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]]+([]+[][[]+([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]+!![]]]()[[]+(+!![])+(+[])]+(![]+[+[]]+([]+[])[[]+([]+[][[]+([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[][[]+([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]])[[]+(+!![])+(+[])]+([]+[][[]])[+!![]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]+([]+!![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+[][[]+([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]+(!![]+[][[]+([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]])[[]+(+!![])+(+[])]+([]+!![])[+!![]]])[+([]+(!![]+!![])+(+[]))])())[[]+((+[])[[]+([]+[][[]+([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[][[]+([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]])[[]+(+!![])+(+[])]+([]+[][[]])[+!![]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]+([]+!![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+[][[]+([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]+(!![]+[][[]+([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]])[[]+(+!![])+(+[])]+([]+!![])[+!![]]]+[])[[]+(+!![])+(+!![])]+([]+![])[+!![]]+(+([]+(!![]+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])))[[]+([]+!![])[+![]]+(!![]+[][[]+([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]])[[]+(+!![])+(+[])]+([]+[])[[]+([]+[][[]+([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[][[]+([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]])[[]+(+!![])+(+[])]+([]+[][[]])[+!![]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]+([]+!![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+[][[]+([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]+(!![]+[][[]+([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]])[[]+(+!![])+(+[])]+([]+!![])[+!![]]][[]+([]+[][[]])[+!![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+((+[])[[]+([]+[][[]+([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[][[]+([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]])[[]+(+!![])+(+[])]+([]+[][[]])[+!![]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]+([]+!![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+[][[]+([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]+(!![]+[][[]+([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]])[[]+(+!![])+(+[])]+([]+!![])[+!![]]]+[])[[]+(+!![])+(+!![])]+([]+!![])[!![]+!![]+!![]]]](+([]+(!![]+!![]+!![])+(+[])))]([][[]+([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]][[]+([]+[][[]+([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[][[]+([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]])[[]+(+!![])+(+[])]+([]+[][[]])[+!![]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]+([]+!![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+[][[]+([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]+(!![]+[][[]+([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]])[[]+(+!![])+(+[])]+([]+!![])[+!![]]]([]+([]+!![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]+([]+!![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+!![])[+!![]]+([]+[][[]])[+!![]]+(+[![]]+[][[]+([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]])[+([]+(+!![])+(+!![]))]+([]+![])[+[]]+([]+[])[[]+([]+![])[+[]]+(!![]+[][[]+([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]])[[]+(+!![])+(+[])]+([]+[][[]])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]+([]+[][[]+([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[][[]+([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]])[[]+(+!![])+(+[])]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[][[]+([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]])[[]+(+!![])+(+[])]+([]+!![])[+!![]]]()[+([]+(+!![])+(+!![]))]+([]+[])[[]+([]+[][[]])[!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+[][[]])[!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]]+([]+[][[]+([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]+!![]]]()[!![]+!![]]+([+[]]+([]+[])[[]+([]+[][[]+([]+![])[+[]]+([]+[][[]])[!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[][[]+([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]])[[]+(+!![])+(+[])]+([]+[][[]])[+!![]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]+([]+!![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+[][[]+([]+![])[+[]]+([]+[][[]])[!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]+(!![]+[][[]+([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]])[[]+(+!![])+(+[])]+([]+!![])[+!![]]])[+([]+(+!![])+(+[]))]+([]+!![])[+![]]+([]+!![])[+!![]]+([]+[][[]])[!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]]+([]+[][[]])[+!![]]+(![]+[+[]]+([]+[])[[]+([]+[][[]+([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[][[]+([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]])[[]+(+!![])+(+[])]+([]+[][[]])[+!![]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]+([]+!![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+[][[]+([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]+(!![]+[][[]+([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]])[[]+(+!![])+(+[])]+([]+!![])[+!![]]])[+([]+(!![]+!![])+(+[]))]+(+(+!+[]+[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]]+[+[]])+[])[+!+[]]+([]+![])[+[]]+([]+!![])[+!![]]+(!![]+[][[]+([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]])[[]+(+!![])+(+[])]+((+[])[[]+([]+[][[]+([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[][[]+([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]])[[]+(+!![])+(+[])]+([]+[][[]])[+!![]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]+([]+!![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+[][[]+([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]+(!![]+[][[]+([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]])[[]+(+!![])+(+[])]+([]+!![])[+!![]]]+[])[[]+(+!![])+(+!![])]+[][[]+([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]][[]+([]+[][[]+([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[][[]+([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]])[[]+(+!![])+(+[])]+([]+[][[]])[+!![]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]+([]+!![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+[][[]+([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]+(!![]+[][[]+([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]])[[]+(+!![])+(+[])]+([]+!![])[+!![]]]([]+([]+!![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]+([]+!![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+!![])[+!![]]+([]+[][[]])[+!![]]+(+[![]]+[][[]+([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]])[+([]+(+!![])+(+!![]))]+([]+!![])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+([]+[][[]+([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+(+([]+(!![]+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])))[[]+([]+!![])[+![]]+(!![]+[][[]+([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]])[[]+(+!![])+(+[])]+([]+[])[[]+([]+[][[]+([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[][[]+([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]])[[]+(+!![])+(+[])]+([]+[][[]])[+!![]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]+([]+!![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+[][[]+([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]+(!![]+[][[]+([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]])[[]+(+!![])+(+[])]+([]+!![])[+!![]]][[]+([]+[][[]])[+!![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+((+[])[[]+([]+[][[]+([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[][[]+([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]])[[]+(+!![])+(+[])]+([]+[][[]])[+!![]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]+([]+!![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+[][[]+([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]+(!![]+[][[]+([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]])[[]+(+!![])+(+[])]+([]+!![])[+!![]]]+[])[[]+(+!![])+(+!![])]+([]+!![])[!![]+!![]+!![]]]](+([]+(!![]+!![]+!![])+(+[])))+([]+!![])[!![]+!![]+!![]])()(([]+[])[[]+([]+[][[]])[!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+[][[]])[!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]]+([]+[][[]+([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]+!![]]]())[!![]+!![]]+(+([]+(+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])))[[]+([]+!![])[+![]]+(!![]+[][[]+([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]])[[]+(+!![])+(+[])]+([]+[])[[]+([]+[][[]+([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[][[]+([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]])[[]+(+!![])+(+[])]+([]+[][[]])[+!![]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]+([]+!![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+[][[]+([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]+(!![]+[][[]+([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]])[[]+(+!![])+(+[])]+([]+!![])[+!![]]][[]+([]+[][[]])[+!![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+((+[])[[]+([]+[][[]+([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[][[]+([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]])[[]+(+!![])+(+[])]+([]+[][[]])[+!![]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]+([]+!![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+[][[]+([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]+(!![]+[][[]+([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]])[[]+(+!![])+(+[])]+([]+!![])[+!![]]]+[])[[]+(+!![])+(+!![])]+([]+!![])[!![]+!![]+!![]]]](+([]+(!![]+!![])+(+[])))+([]+![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[+!![]]+[][[]+([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]][[]+([]+[][[]+([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[][[]+([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]])[[]+(+!![])+(+[])]+([]+[][[]])[+!![]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]+([]+!![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+[][[]+([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]+(!![]+[][[]+([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]])[[]+(+!![])+(+[])]+([]+!![])[+!![]]]([]+([]+!![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]+([]+!![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+!![])[+!![]]+([]+[][[]])[+!![]]+(+[![]]+[][[]+([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]])[+([]+(+!![])+(+!![]))]+([]+!![])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+([]+[][[]+([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+(+([]+(!![]+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])))[[]+([]+!![])[+![]]+(!![]+[][[]+([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]])[[]+(+!![])+(+[])]+([]+[])[[]+([]+[][[]+([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[][[]+([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]])[[]+(+!![])+(+[])]+([]+[][[]])[+!![]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]+([]+!![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+[][[]+([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]+(!![]+[][[]+([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]])[[]+(+!![])+(+[])]+([]+!![])[+!![]]][[]+([]+[][[]])[+!![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+((+[])[[]+([]+[][[]+([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[][[]+([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]])[[]+(+!![])+(+[])]+([]+[][[]])[+!![]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]+([]+!![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+[][[]+([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]+(!![]+[][[]+([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]])[[]+(+!![])+(+[])]+([]+!![])[+!![]]]+[])[[]+(+!![])+(+!![])]+([]+!![])[!![]+!![]+!![]]]](+([]+(!![]+!![]+!![])+(+[])))+([]+!![])[!![]+!![]+!![]])()(([]+[])[[]+([]+[][[]])[!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+[][[]])[!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]]+([]+[][[]+([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]+!![]]]())[!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[][[]+([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]])[[]+(+!![])+(+[])]+([][[]]+[])[!![]+!![]]+([]+!![])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+([][[]+([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]]+[])[+([]+(+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![]))]+(+([]+(!![]+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])))[[]+([]+!![])[+![]]+(!![]+[][[]+([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]])[[]+(+!![])+(+[])]+([]+[])[[]+([]+[][[]+([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[][[]+([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]])[[]+(+!![])+(+[])]+([]+[][[]])[+!![]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]+([]+!![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+[][[]+([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]+(!![]+[][[]+([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]])[[]+(+!![])+(+[])]+([]+!![])[+!![]]][[]+([]+[][[]])[+!![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+((+[])[[]+([]+[][[]+([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[][[]+([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]])[[]+(+!![])+(+[])]+([]+[][[]])[+!![]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]+([]+!![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+[][[]+([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]+(!![]+[][[]+([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]])[[]+(+!![])+(+[])]+([]+!![])[+!![]]]+[])[[]+(+!![])+(+!![])]+([]+!![])[!![]+!![]+!![]]]](+([]+(!![]+!![]+!![])+(+[])))+([]+![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[+!![]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+([]+!![])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+([]+(+(+!+[]+(!+[]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+[+!+[]]+[+[]]+[+[]]+[+[]])))[+[]]+([]+[][[]])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]+([][[]+([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]]+[])[+([]+(+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![]))]+([]+![])[+[]]+([][[]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+[][[]])[!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]]+([]+[][[]+([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+([]+!![])[!![]+!![]+!![]]][[]+([]+[][[]+([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]](![]+[])+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+([+[]]+![]+[][[]+([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]])[+([]+(!![]+!![])+(+[]))]+([+[]]+![]+[][[]+([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]])[+([]+(!![]+!![])+(+[]))])())[[]+([][[]+([]+!![])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+([]+[][[]])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]+([]+!![])[+!![]]+([]+[][[]])[!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]]+([]+!![])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]+!![]]]()+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[][[]+([]+![])[+[]]+([]+![])[!![]+!![]]+([]+![])[+!![]]+([]+!![])[+![]]])[[]+(+!![])+(+[])]+([]+[][[]])[!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]]+([]+[][[]])[+!![]]]([]))()
```

Answer (score 1):

## [simply](https://github.com/ismael-miguel/simply), 321 bytes

This is a very verbose language that I've been writing for a while now.

It uses the canvas module, to do all the drawing.
This is based on the HTML `<canvas>` and the JavaScript `canvas.getContent('2d')`.

```go
$C=call!CANVAS->init(256,256)def&p($x$y$R$G$B$A)call$C->fillRect($x$y,1,1&str_concat("rgba("$R','$G','$B','&div($A,255)')'))&p($a=126$b=127$F=255,0,0$F)&p($b$b,0$F,0$F)&p($c=128$b,0,0$F$F)&p($d=129$b$F,0,0$F)&p($d$b,0$F,0$b)&p($a$c,0,0,0$F)&p($b$c$F$F$F$F)&p($c$c$F,0,0$F)&p($c$c,0,0$F$b)&p($d$c,0$F,0$F)&p($d$c,0,0$F$b);
```

This generates a 256x256 canvas, due to the X and Y being in the 0-255 range.

**Result (raw and zoomed):**
[image: Raw result]
[image: Zoomed in result]

---

### Explanation:

**Generates the canvas, 29 bytes**

```go
$C=call!CANVAS->init(256,256)
```

All it does is really that: create the canvas.
It's assigned to a local variable, because of the next point.

**Draws the pixels, 95 bytes**

```go
def&p($x$y$R$G$B$A)call$C->fillRect($x$y,1,1&str_concat("rgba("$R','$G','$B','&div($A,255)')'))
```

Defines the function that will do all the drawing.
There's no scope opening, so, it takes the next statement as the whole function code.
This is similar to C-like `if(cond) do_something();`, but applied to functions.

This gives access to the local variables to that single statement, which won't happen for a function with a new scope.

**Pixel data, 197 bytes**

```go
&p($a=126$b=127$F=255,0,0$F)&p($b$b,0$F,0$F)&p($c=128$b,0,0$F$F)&p($d=129$b$F,0,0$F)&p($d$b,0$F,0$b)&p($a$c,0,0,0$F)&p($b$c$F$F$F$F)&p($c$c$F,0,0$F)&p($c$c,0,0$F$b)&p($d$c,0$F,0$F)&p($d$c,0,0$F$b);
```

All the data to draw.

There's a mix between commas (`,`) and variables glued to values.
This is intentional, as the language doesn't care (much) if there's a comma or not, as long as they are 2 distinct tokens.

---

### Ungolfed code:

```go
// Creates the 256x256 canvas, and displays it
// This uses a global variable (starts with %), so it is available in &putPixel
Set %canvas to the result of calling !CANVAS->init(256, 256).

// This is the function that does the drawing
Define the function &putPixel with the arguments $x, $y, $R, $G, $B, $A.
Begin.
    // $alpha has to be between 0 and 1, so, needs to be divided by 255.
    Set $alpha to the result of calling &div($A, 255).
    
    // Sets $style to the rgba(...) value for the pixel
    Set $style to the result of calling &str_concat("rgba(", $R, ',', $G, ',', $B, ',', $alpha, ')').
    
    // This is the function that does the drawing
    Call the function %canvas->fillRect($x, $y, 1, 1, $style).
End.

// From here on, everything is just the pixel data

//  Red
Call the function &putPixel(126, 127, 255,   0,   0, 255).
//  Green
Call the function &putPixel(127, 127,   0, 255,   0, 255).
//  Blue
Call the function &putPixel(128, 127,   0,   0, 255, 255).
//  Red
Call the function &putPixel(129, 127, 255,   0,   0, 255).
//  Dark Yellow (previous red + transparent green)
Call the function &putPixel(129, 127,   0, 255,   0, 127).

// ⬛ Black
Call the function &putPixel(126, 128,   0,   0,   0, 255).
// ⬜ White
Call the function &putPixel(127, 128, 255, 255, 255, 255).
//  Red
Call the function &putPixel(128, 128, 255,   0,   0, 255).
//  Dark pink (previous red + transparent blue)
Call the function &putPixel(128, 128,   0,   0, 255, 127).
//  Blue
Call the function &putPixel(129, 128,   0, 255,   0, 255).
//  Dark sea-blue (previous blue + transparent green)
Call the function &putPixel(129, 128,   0,   0, 255, 127).
```

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript, <s>299 ... 257</s> 252 bytes

Yeah... finally, the 256-bytes barrier was broken. This is improvement of kaya3 [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/revisions/250808/7) (329 bytes)

```js
document.write`<canvas id=Y>`,c=Y.getContext`2d`
p=(x,y,a,...r)=>{c.fillStyle=`rgba(${r},${a/255})`;c.fillRect(x,y,1,1)}
(0x13112fb565921390e1525ad52e2debb235fdb48dc495b7b695e1605n+'')
.replace(/.{6}/g,x=>p(...[...x].map(u=>[0,126,127,128,129,255][u])))
```

Initialization & function: 120 bytes

Test-case code: 131 bytes (after remove one new-line character before last line)

Draw pixel explanation: we change BigInt hex num into long decimal string with 66 digits. We split long string into eleven 6-digit chunks and treat each digit as index. Then map each index to color value using array `[0,126,127,128,129,255]` and call put-pixel function `p` with parameters from such mapped chunk

Comment: Save 4 bytes by calling functions as a [tagged template](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#tagged_templates)

Comment: @Samathingamajig thanks for advice! - answer updated

Comment: nice work, JS below 256 bytes and a function that would work on different pixels as well. your should allow @kaya3 to work on his solution under the same conditions ;-)